# wrap text inside label not working

Tags: html, css

I am using option button with image and have put text below each image. But if you see 2nd image in first row in [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/4270/) you can see due to long name there is more gap between images than on 2nd row. How can i word wrap so it expands vertically. I tried `word-break: break-word` but not working.

Can someone tell how to fix it?

Comment: What is the expected result? The fiddle works as expected. Floated elements, one of them with a long text that makes more width the parent.

Comment: Why don't you give it fixed width like you have in commented css code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give a max-width attribute to the label

The reason the word isn't wrapping is because it doesn't know how wide you want the label to be before it wraps

I added max-width:60px; as an example

Answer (score 3):

Add a defined width so the div will push the text down if it does over said with.

```
label{
  float:left;
  text-align:center;
  word-break: break-word;
  height:100px;
  width:50px;
  padding:15px;
}
```

Your CSS code should look something like this, all I added was the defined width (which you really already had, just incorrectly commented) and the padding to give the images some space.

[Code Example](https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/4271/)

Answer (score 0):

The text is nested inside a widthless label tag. Hence, the text has unlimited space to spread itself on. Delimit your text by adding width to the label tag.

```
label{
  width:70px;
}
```